# A stick is randomly broken into 3 pieces. What is the expected length of the middle part? [Wrong Solution]

Tags: probability

The full question is as follows:

> A stick is broken into 3 pieces, by randomly choosing two points along
>   its unit length, and cutting it. What is the expected length of the
>   middle part?

I've understood the correct solution, which is to integrate $|x-y|$ over the unit square, resulting in a solution of $\frac{1}{3}$.

However, I'd like to present an alternate solution, and would like to know why it is wrong:

Wrong Solution:

Let $X$ and $Y$ correspond to the random variables of the two chosen points.

Then we have two cases - either $X\geq Y$ or $X<Y$

Due to the symmetry, we can just consider $X \geq Y$.

Suppose $X = x$, then the expected value of $X - Y$ is $\frac{x}{2} $ by symmetry, since Y is also distributed uniformly in $[0,x]$. This, together with the fact that $X$ is uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$, implies that the expected value of $X-Y$ has to be $\frac{1}{4}$ instead when $X \geq Y$.

(The argument for $X<Y$ follows in a similar manner)

Why is this line of reasoning wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that $X$ is not uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$ because it is defined as a maximum of two uniform random variables. It has a $Beta(2,1)$ distribution.

Comment: Thank you! I understand it now (: Btw, do you have a link for the maximum having a Beta(2,1) distribution?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Order_statistics_sampled_from_a_uniform_distribution. $Beta(2,1)$ has a pdf of $2x$ so it's actually a very simple distribution. You can work out the integral yourself and arrive at a correct result of $\frac{1}{3}$ .